# Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'URL' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy:

Tags: c#, cors, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I thought I'd allowed access to all origins but I'm still getting this error.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:60248/api/page/1' from origin
> 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin
> requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome,
> chrome-extension, https.

**UPDATE** the error has now changed after adding suggested code changes. It's now as follows:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:60248/api/page/1' from
> origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check:
> Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

In Startup.cs I have this:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(name: "AllowAll",
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .WithMethods("PUT", "DELETE", "GET");
                });
        });
```

In my controller I have this:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class PageController : ControllerBase
{
    ...

    [EnableCors("AllowAll")]
    [HttpGet("{id:int}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetPageData(int id)
    {
       ...
```

This is the Angular service that calls the endpoint:

```
export class PageContentService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getContent(id: number): Observable<PageContent> {

    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: headers
    }

    return this.http.get<PageContent>(`http://localhost:60248/api/page/${id}`, httpOptions);
  }
}
```

I thought that would take care of it, but clearly not.

What else do I need to do?

Comment: Show us the Javascript code you use to use - have you use the correct URL? Does the URL have an `http` or `https` prefix?

Comment: Added Angular service that calls the endpoint.

Comment: Are you sure there's no weird characters in the URL? The error message states that you are not using `http`. Have you set a base URL perhaps?

Comment: Interesting I'll look into that...

Comment: Please stop changing your question - it has been answered and you are now asking a NEW question. Mark it as answered as the people who have spent time helping you are not infinite resources and should be rewarded for helping.

Comment: Your original error is gone, and you have a new one.

Comment: "semantics", but I'm just trying to help you make best use of the site. We see questions like this all the time. You can't expect people to keep modifying their answers as you hit further issues.

Comment: @DavidG The question title has not changed, and that error still occurs. The problem has not been fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need two more things:

1. Like vivek said, in your `Configure` method add `.UseCors()` to your request pipeline.
2. Add `.AllowAnyHeader()` to the CORS-Config in the policy builder, I think the `Content-Type`-Header isn't allowed by default.

Comment: Did you mean `AllowAnyHeader()`? I added that and also the `UseCors` (see updated example) . I now get a slightly different message ending with: "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request."

Comment: Add AllowAnyMethod() also

Comment: I've updated the question with the new error message

Comment: @CompanyDroneFromSector7G You can't keep updating the question - once you have an answer the makes the error go away, then this question is done.

Comment: @DavidG the error has changed slightly but it's still there, so the question is not done.

Comment: And then the next, error, and the next error, and the next error etc. Your question has been answered. If you have more questions, ask a new question.

Comment: Yes, I meant `AllowANyHeaders()` ;) - thankfully I usually have IntelliSense to save me.

Comment: Please check the ul of request, whether is it correct or not

Comment: @CompanyDroneFromSector7G Did you add just `.UseCors()` to the `Configure` method?

Comment: @Squirrelkiller Yes I did, I updated the question with that but 'somebody' got stressy about it. (I didn't want to take away his moment of power by putting it back)

Comment: There's no "power", but @Squirrelkiller should be recognised for their work in answering your original question.

Comment: @viveknuna Yes the URL in the error message looks correct.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the middleware also.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
...

        app.UseCors();

...
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand the downvote here, this seems like the logical next step to a working CORS.

Comment: @Squirrelkiller Agreed, downvoter please let me know the reason

Comment: Me too - I'm not sure either (voted up to compensate) :(